# Workflow task list - Add an additional column of information from a related list item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-tasks-list

A new request came up to me to have a task (in the default workflow tasks list, generated by a workflow) show an additional column next to the task's Title (column) which shows information from the Task's related list item. For example, I may have a Title of a task called "Review" (many tasks created to many different people for review) and then next to it need to have a column which contains a group or category for the review like "Engineering" for the specific task item. This would help the end users because they could see which group or category needs to review it, without this they would need to go into the task to see that level of detail. The reason this is needed is because there are many coordinators needing to review many tasks but only a subset of them are responsible for different groups or categories. Therefore they would like to be able to create views of their my task list to filter out unneeded groups or categories.

I have gone down a couple of rabbit holes and have been unable to fulfill the request above. I am hoping someone here has had some experience with this and could provide me some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the information from the Task's related list item, you could create the lookup column to look up the items from related list.

If the lookup column cannot achieve your requirement, could you please provide more details about the issue?